# can't work $itemObject->getProduct()->getName() in magento

Tags: magento, product, quote, ecommerce-sales

I m trying to get product information through item object using `getProduct()` method of `Mage_Sales_Quote_Item` class without a for loop.  Below is my nonworking code.  How do I get data of product using the `getProduct()` method?

```
 $quoteId = 5;
    $quoteItemObject = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId)->getAllItems();
    echo $quoteItemObject->getProduct()->getName();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$quoteItemObject returns an array of all items in the quote but not a separate item. You need to "foreach" it and get information for each item separately. Try something like this:

```
foreach ($quoteItemObject as $item) {
    echo $item->getProduct()->getName();
}
```

Comment: It works,thank you.Yes You are right. getAllItems() method return item array not item object. thanks for understanding this concept and fast reply